# Run SQL query on the Table in Memory

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 2 Tables which I have Joined using SQL Query

```
DataTable Table = Select FacilityIssueDetails.FacilityNo,LCPaymentDetails.BillNo, FacilityIssueDetails.FStatus,LCPaymentDetails.BankName , LCPaymentDetails.Supplier, FacilityIssueDetails.BaseAmount,FacilityIssueDetails.Currency, FacilityIssueDetails.FacilityAmountINR, LCPaymentDetails.PAmountINR , FacilityIssueDetails.LCAmountPaid, FacilityIssueDetails.LCAmountRemaining,FacilityIssueDetails.IssueDate, FacilityIssueDetails.ExpiryDate, LCPaymentDetails.LCNo 
                  from FacilityIssueDetails,LCPaymentDetails 
                  where FacilityIssueDetails.FacilityNo = LCPaymentDetails.LCNo
```

Now I want to Run another SQL Query on the Table stored in memory.

How to do it? It's a select query.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your first query to join two tables?

Comment: Ok, but I didn't see "join" in there. Do you want to do this with SQL or Linq?

Comment: Actually my main work is to join those 2 tables then again run a query and get the more perfect table 
IN second query i want to see only those transaction which are open and bank

Sooo i dont know how to do it, I dont know LInq and Confused how to use SQL query

Comment: Why can't you simply improve the first query to give you what you want?

Comment: Sorry friends the Requirement got changed so all this is not required now

Thanks for Helping Me out

Comment: Then delete your question. no one needs question without answer in here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method. Note, that its performance is slow comparing with `SELECT` against database.